# Please make a badge for having the highest reputation

Tags: discussion, feature-request, badges

If no badge currently exists for this, then I suggest that when a user reaches the top `x` reputation, or the highest reputation, they get awarded a gold badge. Only one of these badges will exist at any time on a given site. If a user still has the top reputation after one year then they are given a diamond badge (only one time).

Comment: I don't think you are allowed to agree with yourself here.

Comment: That would be a world gone topsturvey.

Comment: @TheTXI: Yes you can.

Comment: @Pesto: Good point.

Comment: @TheTXI: You are the best!

Comment: I want a superdownvote for this one.

Comment: @Welbog: Agreed.

Comment: I am thinking here the people are not ready to ask ,, Jeff. Please tell me if this is wrong close it ..  and Other Please Vote for Close

Comment: Kirsh: You are free to suggest anything you want. If people are downvoting you on Meta, chances are it is because people do not agree with your suggestion. That doesn't mean you were wrong to ask.

Comment: @Pesto, sometimes, a period demands a wide berth.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't see how this is useful. It has been demonstrated over all the websites so far that once someone grabs the lead, they generally are -not- going to give it up. For a while there was a bit of a back and forth between myself, Atwood, Olafur, and Skeeter for #1 on Meta, but Atwood has pulled away to the point where unless he took a few days off you can't catch him. The same is true for StackOverflow (Skeet would have to take several years off at this point) and I think a couple of users on SuperUser are already pulling away from the pack.

Comment: He's probably gunning for the badge at SU.

Comment: its OK .. There will be some one will happy that if the user reached No.1 and Left away also ...Still the user will remind that moment

Comment: Of Course .. I am trying that .. What Wrong.. I cant reach SO as NO:1 and Same in M-SO .. I am trying for SO..So I am asking that...

Comment: If there was a Rosetta Stone package for "Engrish" I need to go and invest in it.

Comment: It's been over a year since you've said this but you made me laugh so hard!

Answer (score 2):

Yellow Jersey?

You mean Jon Skeet's 900+ badges aren't enough?

Comment: One can *never* have too many virtual items of little to no value

Comment: That will be only one at time .. my request only one at time in SO or SM or SU

Comment: Well considering theres a daily rep limit on all sites and it's the same limit and SO predates any of the other sites by 6+ months, I think the Jon Skeet comment still applied. Or do you envisions someone on SU or SF overtaking his 80k+ rep on SO?

Comment: Nothing is impossible in the world

Comment: @Kirsh: Tons of stuff is impossible. Like the halting problem. Or brainwashing TXI into thinking ponies are hideous.

Comment: Not to mention cold fusion.

Comment: They had cold fusion in that Spiderman movie so it's real.

Comment: Spider-Man - And the only real thing about it was that this time Molina kept the idol.